# Blender 4.0: Rigify Rig Layers on Viewport Ntab not populating. Blender 3.6 works ok

Tags: customization, rigify, layers

Setup: Blender 4.0.2 Animation with two (2) Rigify-rigged characters in same scene.

Problem #1: 3D Viewport; Ntab; 'Item/Rig Layers' is blank (not populated). '../Rig Main Properties' and '.../Properties'tab is works fine (i.e. I can't see the rig layers in either object or pose mode.
Problem #2: Cannot create a simple rigged human using the MPFBv2.0-a3 create a human from scratch. Blender 4.0 is looking for a checked 'import-export wavefront object' preference that no longer exists in blender 4.0

Fix Attempts tried:

1. Rig 'Layers Tab' works fine under 3.6 on this and all previous 'saved' projects versions of this scene. Does not work on 4.0.

2)Rig_ui.py does not exist in any version of file.
I did find python file 'name.Rigify_ui.py' (where 'name' is my character rig's name ex: 'Kirk.Rigify_ui.py') and this subroutine has the 'def register();' subroutine in it with a 'register()' command at the end.
I ran this routine from the 'scripting' interface but it did NOT populate the 'Rig Layers' tab.

3. Preferences/Save & Load/'Auto run python scripts' is checked to run scripts on startup.
4. Attempted new Blender 4.0.2 / MPFBv2.0-a3 character creation using the Rigify ver 0.6.9 'New human/From scratch' option. The 'Create Human' button returned an error telling me the 'preferences/Addon/import-export: Wavefront.obj' option must be selected. Note: This option is marked 'Legacy' in version 3.6 and does not exist in 'blender 4.0.2'.
5. Opened Blender 3.6 & created a new/simple/MPFB rigify character and saved blend file. Opened the blend file into blender 4.0 and the same error as described above exists .... 'rig layers' tab is not populated.

Note: I will also submit this into the 'rigify' 'Report a Bug' button on the preferences/add-ons menu

Comment: ah yes it looks messy.  you may want to follow [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/311410/111042) question.  It has to do with removal of "layers" data and replacing with "collections" data.  I do hope there is a compatible solution!

Comment: Here's a [discussion](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/105168) on the rigify add-on site.  You can re-generate only if you kept the original rig, which I didn't

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late, but in case someone else finds this question...

MPFB 2.0-a3 is not compatible with Blender 4. You need the blender 4 specific build in order to use, for example, the new rigify options. You can find information about the different MPFB builds to download here: http://static.makehumancommunity.org/mpfb/downloads.html

In general, when you run into problems with rigify in combination with MPFB, it is not unlikely that this is due to a problem with MPFB rather than with rigify. In those cases, it might be better to ask for support directly from MPFB. This can be done here: https://github.com/makehumancommunity/mpfb2/issues

Comment: Here's a [discussion](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/105168) on the rigify add-on site.  You can re-generate only if you kept the original rig, which I didn't

Comment: [Also here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/312026/111042)