# migrating a rigify script from 3.x to 4.x -- Bone Collections replaced layers

Tags: python, rigify

I am getting errors from pre-4.x "rig_ui.py" scripts that have statements like:

`row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=0, toggle=True, text='Face')`

and according to python docs, *armature.layers* has been removed.   It appears to be replaced by a more complex structure *armature.collections* and perhaps the new property is armature.collections[n].is_visible.

So what would the new statement become?  Something like:

`row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'collections', index=0, toggle=True, text='Face')`,

to use the index=n value, but how to get Rig Layers panel to show up like in 3.6:

[image]

instead of blank:

[image]

The following from the new Rigify >> Generate Rig shows the follow, that doesn't work in a simply copy paste into the older script:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row_table = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for coll in context.active_object.data.collections:
        row_id = coll.get('rigify_ui_row', 0)
        if row_id > 0:
            row_table[row_id].append(coll)
    col = layout.column()
    for row_id in range(min(row_table.keys()), 1 + max(row_table.keys())):
        row = col.row()
        row_buttons = row_table[row_id]
        if row_buttons:
            for coll in row_buttons:
                title = coll.get('rigify_ui_title') or coll.name
                row.prop(coll, 'is_visible', toggle=True, text=title)
        else:
            row.separator()
```

and

```
>>> list(bpy.context.active_object.data.collections[1].items())
[]
```

is empty.  In the hope of helping the helpers, here's a 4.0 file with a 3.6 rig and a 4.0 rig.   [image]

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/105168) to rigify team and hope there's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to a reply to my bug report,  I'm out of luck if I clean up by deleting the original rig and only kept the meta-rig, or if I used (in my cases) a DAZ importer add-on.   On the *original rig*, there will be a Rigify panel that allows for regeneration that will fill in the updated group names:

[image]

As stated by an add-on maintainer: "Upgrade is only implemented for metarigs, because 1) the intended workflow is to keep them around for updates, and 2) updating a generated rig would require parsing and patching the text of the python script datablock. So, in any case, this is a feature request and not a bug."